# How to delete the dat from two tables in yii2 controller

Tags: mysql, yii2, yii2-model

I have Calendar & Notifications Models.. I am deleting data from both models from Calendar Controller.. When I try to delete with the given code, nothing happends both records remins as it is.. and I get redirected to notification controller.. How to fix this redirection..
...\index.php?r=notifications/delete&id=1

I tried die(); statement before redirect and both record got deleted successfully..

```
 public function actionDelete($id)
    {
       // die("deleting");
        if(Calendar::find()->where(['id' =>$id])->one()->delete())
        {
            echo "Calendar Deleted... ...<br>";
            if( Notifications::find()->where(['calndar_id' =>$id])->one()->delete())
            {
                echo "Notification Deleted ....<br>";
                $this->redirect(array('index1','message'=>"Calendar & Respective Notification Deleted Successfully"));
            }
            else
            {
                $this->redirect(array('index1','message'=>"Calendar Deleted Successfully"));

            }

        }
    }
```

Expected result is 
1)Both records should get deleted and will redirects to
 ..\index.php?r=calendar\index

Comment: First of all - you should `return` result of `$this->redirect()`. Second - you should first check if `one()` returned the model otherwise you will get NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each  redirect() function must be used  with return

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
   // die("deleting");
    if(Calendar::find()->where(['id' =>$id])->one()->delete())
    {
        echo "Calendar Deleted... ...<br>";
        if( Notifications::find()->where(['calndar_id' =>$id])->one()->delete())
        {
            echo "Notification Deleted ....<br>";
            return $this->redirect(array('index1','message'=>"Calendar & Respective Notification Deleted Successfully"));
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->redirect(array('index1','message'=>"Calendar Deleted Successfully"));

        }

    }
}
```